# Flex - MATE Framework

Tags: apache-flex, mate

I am new to MATE framework and I have been digging around some sample codes so that i can do the following:

1. On clicking a button (on a canvas)
2. Display a Panel.

The issue is that i am not trying to pass any value hence not sure of how/ what should be defined as sourcekey and targetkey. If this is the case, then how should one define the propertyinjector details.

most examples that are floating around contains details of reading data from a source and populating the same on a UI/ Display component.

Thanks
Srinivasan S

Answer (score 1):

for this one you shouldn't use propertyInjection you should dispatch an event (you can make it custom), then you need to catch the event in the appropriate place and simply do whatever you want with it.